# Google maps wont open using URL launcher in Flutter

Tags: flutter, google-maps, dart, url

I'm very new to flutter.

I've created an app that should open up google maps on click but it wont open.
Please help me out.

`forMap.dart` file (This is the file which has the method to launch google maps):

```
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

class MapUtils {
  MapUtils._();

  static Future<void>openMap(double latitude,double longitude) async {
    String googleUrl = 'https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=$latitude,$longitude';
    if(await canLaunch(googleUrl) != null) {
      await canLaunch(googleUrl);
    } else {
      throw 'Could not open the map.';
   }
 }

}
```

`main.dart` file (This is the file which will use the method of the `forMap.dart` file and launch it):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'forMap.dart';

 void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
 }

 class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
 // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
     title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
      primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
   ),
   home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
   );
 }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {


 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Scaffold(
   appBar: AppBar(
    ),
   body: Center(
    child: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        InkWell(
          onTap: (){
            MapUtils.openMap(38.8977,77.0365);
          },
          child: Text('get map'),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because you have incorrectly calling a function. You're using `await canLaunch(googleUrl);` instead of `await launch(googleUrl);` in the **if** part.

So, your code should be like this:

```
static Future<void> openMap(double latitude,double longitude) async {
  String googleUrl = 'https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=$latitude,$longitude';
  if(await canLaunch(googleUrl) != null) {
    await launch(googleUrl);
  } else {
    throw 'Could not open the map.';
  }
}
```

---

You probably don't need to use `Future<void>` so, change the function name to:

```
static void openMap(double latitude,double longitude) async {
  ...
}
```

Comment: hi is it possible instead of using latitude and longitude, directly opening the launcher with the name of a street?  thanks in advanced

Comment: Yes, it is possible to open the launcher with street names directly. Check the [docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/get-started) here for info.